# How to Remove All Desktop Icons

Tags: desktop-environments, 19.04, .desktop, desktop-icons

In Ubuntu 19.04, how can I make it to where the desktop doesn't try to mirror the desktop folder? I don't want to see any icons on my desktop.

I'm not sure how this is suppose to be by default, but my desktop shows a trash bin, a folder with my user name, and a file I put into /home/username/Desktop. Instead I would like it to show nothing.

I have nemo installed, and I can't tell whether nemo or nautilus is responsible for this, but I'm unable to find settings in either that would remove all desktop icons.

Comment: Neither file manager is responsible. Now it's done by Gnome (new feature).

Comment: I see. That's a sensible default. Is it optional?

Comment: According to Gnome devs it isn't. But you can remove the standard icons you mention in settings.

Comment: Isn't that handled by a Gnome extension nowadays ? Go to extensions.gnome.org, choose Installed extensions, and find Desktop Icons .. and disable it.

Comment: @SorenA Please post this as the answer.

Comment: @SorenA : I don't understand why I have to access a website to change local settings on my computer. Is there some other way? I don't like installing extensions in my browser. GNOME should have an application dedicated to this without fooling with my default browser.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia : Where in settings? I can't find the place where you say I can remove standard icons.

Comment: Use the `Tweaks` application to disable the desktop icons GNOME extension then.

Comment: I think you can do it with gnome-tweak. Can't confirm right now because I'm in a tablet (Android).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either go to [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) to turn off the `Desktop Icons` GNOME Shell extension, or use the `Tweaks` application to do the same thing.

Click on the gear (settings) icon to change the settings for select desktop icons.

Comment: Tweaks worked. Note: The feature was [already turned off](https://i.imgur.com/wjquq75.png), but hitting the gear icon next to the on/off switch allowed me to remove trash-icon and the user-folder icon.

Comment: None of these seem to be working for me... The feature was already turned off.  I've also tried the 'dpkg -r --force-depends gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons' method below and I *still* have icons.  Anyone have any ideas?  Fresh install of 19.04.

Comment: @corey_s did you turn off the trash and home icons in the `Desktop Icons` settings panel?

Comment: Yes...  Eventually just gave up and decided it wasn't worth the effort.  Installed Mint instead -- problem resolved.

Answer (score 4):

This method worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```

This will force removal extension, but updating the system will reinstall it and you will have to remove it again. Holding it with `sudo apt-mark hold gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons` seems to prevent updates from installing.

Comment: Weird thing for me is that if that extension is installed, whether as the deb or locally, I get desktop icons, even if it's apparently disabled. Doing what you suggest (and removing the local copy I had from before) was required to get rid of them. PS. how to reverse what you did with the dpkg / apt-mark commands if I don't like it ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me by [Patrick Dark](https://askubuntu.com/a/1159083/943983)

To remove the **home** icon and **trash** icon execute these two commands in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash false
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**